# How do you size a button to an image in the xcode IDE?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Every week I get some image updates from our graphic designer and often the sizes change. I am now bored of manually working out the size of the image and setting the button size to suit - a process I must follow to ensure the image is displayed at it's natural size for best quality.

Surely there must be a way in xcode to tell it to size the button to suit the background image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the element in the storyboard and under the editor menu, you can select "size to fit content".

[image]

Comment: Thanks @biddster - works a treat (if you can manage to select the item in the storyboard with your mouse! The menu option will not enable when selecting items via the left hand side tree which is frustrating on complex controllers). I have been using this mechanism for a few months now and bumped into a new scenario that may help people - if you have a button with different images for different states you need to ensure that you size to the largest image or the image will not resize on state change.